# How To Save Spring Security Logged In User In Session

Tags: grails, spring-security

This code get's the currently logged in user, using the Spring Security Plugin (acegi):

```
def principalInfo = authenticateService.principal()
def person = null
if (principalInfo != "anonymousUser" && principalInfo.username) {
    person = Person.findByUsername(principalInfo.username)
}
```

I would then like to do:

```
session.user = person
```

This needs to be done after the user logs in. I can't figure out where to put my code to do this. It seem like it should be some place in the Login Controller, but I can't see where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do this? The person is already attached to the principal which is in the session. Call authenticateService.userDomain() to access it.

Comment: That almost works, but if you access any related property if fails, e.g. If I do

person = authenticateService.userDomain() 
company = person.company

I get a LazyInitializationException. Might that be why people have used code like I have above?

Is this where I need a custom userDetailsService? Or would setting eager fetching on solve the problem?

Comment: You could use eager fetching but it's wasteful if you only need it for this use case. To avoid LIEs you can either re-attach the instance (def person = authenticateService.userDomain(); person.attach()) or reload it by id (def person = Person.get(authenticateService.userDomain().id)). This is preferable to eager loading since you can do this only when you know it'll be needed - if you just need String, boolean, or numeric properties then there's no need to reattach or reload.

Comment: person.attach() gave me a NonUniqueObjectException but def person = Person.get(authenticateService.userDomain().id) works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not set a user object directly in the session. However they put a SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT object in the session. This contains the authenticated user.

The following whould work in your gsp:

```
${session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?.authentication?.authenticated}
```

or just directly in your controller code. 
I use this with the Navigation plugin to show certain menu's:

```
static navigation = [
        group:'tabs', 
        order:10, 
        isVisible: {  session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?.authentication?.authenticated }
    ]
```

and, to answer your question, you could get the user object like this:

```
session.SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT?.authentication?.principal?
```